# add_settings_field (exclude categories->reading) wp_category_checklist

Tags: categories, settings-api

In settings/reading, I'm trying to add an option to exclude one or more post categories from main posts/home page.  I'd like to utilize the **wp_category_checklist** function to create the new settings "*field*".

While I have successfully added a checklist under reading settings as intended, I don't see the means by which to get the selected values **output** to the new **exclude_cats** option on save. Meanwhile, I also tried adapting **wp_dropdown_categories** for multiple selection, and have successfully output selected values to the intended **exclude_cats** option, but don't see a way to return the dropdown with **current values pre-selected** in the field/dropdown after saving.

Here's what I have...

```
    class Add_Settings_Field {
    /* Class for adding a new field to the options-reading.php page */
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'admin_init' , array( &$this , 'register_fields' ) );
    }
    public function register_fields() {
        register_setting( 'reading', 'exclude_cats');
        add_settings_field('exclude_cats',
            '<span title="Exclude Category Posts from Main Blog/Posts Page">Exclude Categories</label>',
            array( &$this, 'fields_html' ),
            'reading'
        );
    }
    public function fields_html() {
        // This would suffice if I could set the current values as selected in the resulting dropdown.
        $select_cats = wp_dropdown_categories('&hierarchical=1&hide_empty=0&orderby=name&name=exclude_cats&show_count=0&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&echo=0');
        $select_cats = str_replace( "name='exclude_cats' id=", "name='exclude_cats[]' multiple='multiple' id=", $select_cats );
        echo $select_cats;
        // I would prefer this if only I could get the selected values output to the "exclude_cats" option in wp_options on save.
        // $selected_cats = get_option( 'exclude_cats');
        // $exclude_cats = wp_category_checklist( '', '', $selected_cats, '', '', 1);
        // echo $exclude_cats;
    }
}
new Add_Settings_Field();

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_cats');
function exclude_cats($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home() ) {
        foreach(get_option( 'exclude_cats') as $excluded) $excluded_cats[] = $excluded*-1;
        $excluded = implode(",",$excluded_cats);
        $query->set('cat', $excluded);
    }   return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, to get this to work as intended, I went ahead with the wp_dropdown_categories function approach, settling for a js on-load hack to facilitate selection of currently excluded categories witin the dropdown.

```
/* Add Settings Field --"Exclude Categories"-- under options-reading.php page */
class Add_Settings_Field {
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'admin_init' , array( &$this , 'register_fields' ) );
    }
    public function register_fields() {
        register_setting( 'reading', 'exclude_cats');
        add_settings_field('exclude_cats',
            '<span title="Exclude Category Posts from Main Blog/Posts Page">Exclude Categories</label>',
            array( &$this, 'fields_html' ),
            'reading'
        );
    }
    public function fields_html() {
        # Requires additional hidden field and js hack to set the current values as selected in the resulting dropdown.
        if($selected = get_option( 'exclude_cats')) $selected = implode(",",$selected);
        $excluded_cats = "<input type ='hidden' id='excluded_cats' value='$selected'>"; // to facilitate js selection options onload.
        $args = array(
            'show_option_none' => ' -- Select -- ',
            'hierarchical' => 1,
            'depth' => 1,
            'hide_empty' => 0,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            # 'selected'=> $selected, # accepts integer only, so won't work for multiple selections
            'name' => 'exclude_cats',
            'show_count' => 0,
            'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
            'echo'=> 0
        );
        $select_cats = wp_dropdown_categories($args);
        $select_cats = str_replace( "name='exclude_cats' id=", "name='exclude_cats[]' multiple='multiple' id=", $select_cats );
        echo $select_cats." ".$excluded_cats;
    }
}
new Add_Settings_Field();
```

and for the JS

```
if(jQuery('#exclude_cats').length)
{   jQuery('#exclude_cats option[value="-1"]').val(''); //'show_options_none' returns value of -1, which just won't do...
    var excluded = jQuery('#excluded_cats').val().split(',');
    jQuery(excluded).each(function(){
        jQuery('#exclude_cats option[value="'+this+'"]').prop('selected','selected');
    });
}
```

Comment: Please click on the check mark near the top of your answer to mark it approved. Thanks for coming back and telling us what worked.